# Agrupar datos en excel

Tags: excel, datos, microsoft-office

Tengo esta base de datos en excel de personas, y necesito tratar de agruparlas por su numero de documento, que en algunos esta repetido, de la siguiente manera:

Esta así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero que queden agrupados así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si es posible, se podría insertar una fila para separarlos así? :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tercera no es tan importante.
Alguien podría ayudarme por favor

Comment: Aplica un orden personalizado basándote en la segunda columna y luego en la primera. [Ordenar los datos de una tabla](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/ordenar-los-datos-de-una-tabla-77b781bf-5074-41b0-897a-dc37d4515f27)

Answer (score 2):

tanto si los datos que hay en la columna son numéricos como si son alfa-numéricos o solo palabras los puedes ordenar con la función que tiene Microsoft Excel para ordenar los datos de las filas y las columnas.

Te dejo a continuación un enlace de la página de Microsoft donde vas a encontrar las instrucciones para ordenar la información y un video explicativo.

[Ordenar datos Microsoft Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/ordenar-datos-en-un-rango-o-tabla-62d0b95d-2a90-4610-a6ae-2e545c4a4654)